# Subquery returned more than 1 value - Error Message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the error message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,=> or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Below is a small subset of a larger query, but the part of the query to determine the `Test_Col` value is essentially where I'm running into this issue. The query by itself works, but when I use it as a subquery within the larger query, I get this error message in SQL Server. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

```
select 
    distinct(nml.scode) Loan_Num,
    (select isnull(sum(isnull(t.smtd, 0) + isnull(t.sbeginbudget, 0)), 0) 
     from nmloan nml
     left join property p on nml.hprop = p.hmy
     left join total t on p.hmy = t.hppty
     where nml.hprop in (2380, 3348) 
       and t.umonth between '1/1/1900' and '9/30/2021' 
       and t.ibook = 1 and t.hacct in (1349, 1348, 1347, 1345, 1343, 1342, 1341, 1339, 1338, 1337, 1336, 1334, 1332, 1690, 1682, 1331) 
     group by nml.hprop) Test_Col
from 
    nmloan nml
left join 
    property p on nml.hprop = p.hmy
left join 
    total t on p.hmy = t.hppty
left join 
    acct ac on ac.hmy = t.hacct
left join 
    nmborrower nmb on nml.hmy = nmb.hnmloan
left join 
    person ps on nmb.hmyperson = ps.hmy
left join 
    nmloanterms nmt on nml.hmy = nmt.hloan
left join 
    nmcollateralxref nmx on nml.hmy = nmx.hnmloan
left join 
    nmcollateral nmc on nmx.hnmcollateral = nmc.hmy
left join 
    loanbut1 lb1 on nml.hmy = lb1.hcode
left join 
    NMLedger l ON nml.hmy = l.hNMLoan
left join 
    nmLedgerDetail d on l.hmy = d.hNMLedger
left join 
    loanbut7 lb on nml.hmy = lb.hcode
left join 
    loanbut8 lb8 on nml.hmy = lb8.hcode
left join 
    loanbut9 lb9 on nml.hmy = lb9.hcode
where
    nml.hprop in (2380, 3348) 
    and lb.lrPeriod in ('9/30/2021') 
    and lb9.lrnDate in ('9/30/2021')
group by 
    nml.hprop, nml.scode
```

Comment: In your subquery, you have `group by nml.hprop)` A subquery should return a SINGLE scalar value for each row. Obviously you expect otherwise by including the GROUP BY clause. How to fix it? You change the query to do just that - return a single value. How to do that specifically requires knowledge of your schema and your goal.

Comment: Another problem is your use of DISTINCT in the outer query that also includes a GROUP BY clause. I suggest you give your query much more thought - those generally do not belong together within the same scope of a query. For more information you can simply search on the error message to find similar discussions and suggestions for improvement / correction.

Comment: Possibly you need to define a CTE with your `group by` query that projects the `hprop` column along with its summed result then `left join` onto the cte later in the query

Comment: `distinct(nml.scode)` also implies that you may have the wrong idea about what `distinct` does. It operates on the whole select list not just the column you have in brackets

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback Martin and SMor! Created my first large report and definitely, I would say, an advance beginner. Let me ask the question in a different way. How should I refine the code to produce multiple results in a subquery instead only one result?

Comment: You'll need to explain your requirement / goal, and not just ask about the error.  It's likely you chose the wrong form to solve your problem.  State the overall problem clearly.  Try to reduce the question, by removing anything that isn't required to ask the _basic_ question.  If you don't need 30 tables to ask the basic question, don't include 30 tables in your query (problem statement).  Reduce the test case to just that which is needed.

Comment: For instance, your question could have been stated using the following base SQL as a starting point, and also including a more complete problem description about what you wanted to produce by that `SELECT list`. Here's the minimal SQL you could have used: `SELECT x, (SELECT ...) AS test_col FROM JoinResult AS t GROUP BY x;`  Nothing else was really necessary, except for a very clear problem description based on that reduced query.

Comment: Points to ponder before you go any further: what does `DISTINCT` actually do, is it wise to just throw it at a query to make duplicates go away, why are there duplicates in the first place (perhaps the joins need rethinking)? Should every join be `left join`, perhaps they should be `inner join`, perhaps they should be pre-grouped, perhaps they need better join conditions? Does it make sense to have `where` on a column coming from a `left join`, perhaps it should be in the `on`? Is `'9/30/2021'` the correct way to do dates, shouldn't it be an unambiguous format like `'20213009'`? ....

Comment: .... Why is `nml.hprop` in the `group by` if you are not selecting it? Is the subquery meant to be returning multiple rows? If so perhaps it should be a `join` or an `apply`. These are questions you need to ask yourself in order to understand what your query is doing. Otherwise you are guessing in the dark, and even if you get an answer here you will not understand it.

Comment: It appears that you are intending to calculate a "total"-based calculation related to the nmloan and property records already selected in the outer query.  In that case, you should not re-reference these tables in your subquery, but instead reference the outer tables.  Try something like: (select ... from total t where t.hppty = p.hmy and t.umonth < '2021-09-30' and t.ibook = 1 and t.hacct in (...) ) Test_Col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that since my subquery's alias, nml, has the same alias as the parent query, nml (for the nmLoan table), it was did not work.

Upon changing my subquery's alias to nl and leaving the parent query's alias to nml, that actually worked and I was able to generate multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server DB if your subquery is written after the `select` command where we wrote field name list, then your subquery must be return only one record and only one field, else you will get an error. In your script, you wrote subquery before the `from` command,  after this `Loan_Num,`. I did a little research on your subquery. Your subquery will return more than 1 record in most cases. The reason is that you wrote `group by nml.hprop` and after the `where` command you wrote this condition `nml.hprop in (2380, 3348)`. I would have written this query for you myself, but I don't know your business logic and what need you. If your subquery must return more than 1 record, so you must join this subquery to the main query, using `inner join` or `left join`, you can not write this subquery on the field list.